Monitor calibration with DataVision Spyder2
I have a DataVision Spyder 2 that I used for years under Windows, but would now like to use to calibrate the displays on my Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS system. It's plugged into USB and reports like this:
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 085c:0200 ColorVision, Inc. Spyder 2
However, when I try to use it, the process gets through questions about which display I want to calibrate and more, tells me to position the device, but then when I tell it to start, it fails with this report: "Calibration failed! An internal error occurred that could not be recovered [...]"

Each time I try, the software seems to add a new device to the list. Any other than the first results in immediate shutdown of the calibration dialog, but the first proceeds to questions and the calibration page before finally failing.

I have no idea where to start with trying to fix this. Can anyone give any ideas or guidance?
